# Im new in django I'm using gitpod workspace and trying to set up an authentication system with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

Im trying to set up an authentication system with django-allauth and  to customize the allauth login templates I need to make copies of them in my own templates/allauth directory, I'm using gitpod.
this is the command I'm using to copy

```
cp -r ../.pip.modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/templates/* ./templates/allauth/
```

but Im getting this error message

**cp: cannot stat '../.pip.modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/templates/*': No such file or directory**

this are the installed apps in setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS =

 [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]
```

Comment: have you checked if that path you trying to copy from exists?

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, it was typo error